# How to pass parameters for this code to work

Tags: python

I am doing this exercise of the book "Violent Python", it's a UNIX password cracker. The book gives for granted that you have passed the password name and the salt as parameters somewhere so it will work, but the original parameters needed are not declared anywhere. Where should I pass them / declare a variable  ?

```
import crypt



def testPass(cryptPass):
    salt = cryptPass[0:2]
    dictFile = open('/home/cf/Downloads/CH1/dictionary.txt','r')
    for word in dictFile.readlines():
        word = word.strip('\n')
        cryptWord = crypt.crypt(word,salt)
        if (cryptWord == cryptPass):
            print "[+] Found Password: "+word+"\n"
            return
        print "[-] Password Not Found.\n"
        return

def main():
    passFile = open('/home/cf/Downloads/CH1/passwords.txt')
    for line in passFile.readlines():
        if":" in line:
            user = line.split(':')[0]
            cryptPass = line.split(':')[1].strip('')
            print "[*] Cracking Password For: " + user
            testPass(cryptPass)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You appear to extract them from `passwords.txt`.

Comment: According to your code, `salt` takes the first two characters of `cryptPass` (`salt = cryptPass[0:2]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you `passwords.txt` looks like

```
victim: HX9LLTdc/jiDE: 503:100:Iama Victim:/home/victim:/bin/sh
root: DFNFxgW7C05fo: 504:100: Markus Hess:/root:/bin/bash
```

then the `main` function opens this file, and for each line containing a colon it parses out the user and the encrypted password (`victim`/`root` and `HX9LLTdc/jiDE`/ `DFNFxgW7C05fo` respectively). The encrypted password is then passed to the `testPass` function and the first two characters of it are assumed to be the salt.

Comment: Thank you for explaining further, now I get it but looks like there is a problem with the func that checks the dictionary file, as it's not cracking the victim password.

Comment: Do you get a specific error? Are you working on Linux (the `crypt` module is only available on Linux)? Does your `dictionary.txt` contain the word `egg` (`HX9LLTdc/jiDE` decrypted with the salt `HX` returns `egg`)?

Comment: Yes, it does ... might be a route problem ? I get no errors when executing it nor when debugging

Comment: Solved, it was a whitespace missing here : cryptPass = line.split(':')[1].strip(' ') - So it was only getting the first character of the salt.